# merging geometry in three.js is not working

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js, geometry

A path is changed dynamically. So,

previous render function was, 
(LENGTH, getPosition(), RADIUS, MATERIAL, SCENE are already  set)

```
var prevPosition = getPosition();
for(var i =0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    drawPath(getPosition());
}

function drawPath(currentPosition) {
    var spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([prevPosition, currentPosition]);
    var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(spline, 1, RADIUS);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, MATERIAL);
    SCENE.add(mesh);
}
```

previous render method works very well. 
I changed this for performance.

modified render function is,

```
var mergedGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
function drawPath(currentPosition) {
    var spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([prevPosition, currentPosition]);
    var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(spline, 1, RADIUS);
    mergedGeometry.merge(geometry);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry, MATERIAL);
    SCENE.add(mesh);
}
```

mesh is not displayed.
I don't know why.
Do you know why does not this work?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've confused geometry for a mesh. Geometry is a component of a mesh. You want to add to your geometry, cast it into a new mesh object, and add that new mesh to the scene.

Try:

```
var mergedGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var prevPosition = getPosition();
for(var i =0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    drawPath(getPosition());
}

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry, MATERIAL);
SCENE.add(mesh);


function drawPath(currentPosition) {
    var spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([prevPosition, currentPosition]);
    var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(spline, 1, RADIUS);
    mergedGeometry.merge(geometry);
}
```

If you get stuck, there is a functioning mesh merge fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mt2zbb9k/